# Convert Char Array to String in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am new to programming, particularly in C#, and I thought I'd start with something simple like a text reverser. I thought I'd take it a little further and also make it a Palindrome checker. The problem is I can't seem to convert the array back into a string to check it to the original input.

```
string Inp = "1";  // user input

Console.WriteLine("Input a word to reverse"); // user inputs word
Inp = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine()); // input gets converted to string

char[] charArray = Inp.ToCharArray(); // converts char to array
Array.Reverse(charArray); // reverses array

if (Inp == charArray) { // compares user input to the array - does not work
    Console.WriteLine(Inp + " is a Palindrome"); // writes the input with text afterwards
} else {
    Console.WriteLine(Inp + " is not a palindrome");
}
```

I have tried things like `Convert.ToString` and other versions of that but it didn't seem to work. I tried creating `new string = (charArray)` to create a new string bur that didn't work either.
Thank you.

EDIT: It gives me this error:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'char[]'

Also, a little unrelated, but are there too many annotations? Should I do less?
And did I ask the question correctly or is there something I did wrong and missed out?

Comment: `if (Inp.SequenceEqual(charArray)) { // Palindrome } else { // no Palindrome } `, Btw, you don't need to convert a string to string.

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand what your problem is, this just works:

Code:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var chars = new[] {'a', 'b', 'c'};
            var s = new string(chars);
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

> abc

For your comparison problem, here's a more robust way on how to do it:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var sourceChars = new[] {'a', 'b', 'c'};
            var targetChars = new[] {'C', 'B', 'A'};

            Array.Reverse(sourceChars);

            var sourceString = new string(sourceChars);
            var targetString = new string(targetChars);

            var isMatch = string.Equals(sourceString, targetString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

            Console.WriteLine(isMatch);
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

> True